# Numpy.dot TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Why am I getting this error when using `np.dot(a,b.T)`:

```
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') 
               to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

a and b are of type `numpy.ndarray`. My `NumPy` version is 1.11.0.

Comment: You need to show a self-contained example with sample data.  The error message is saying that some of your data are floats and some are strings.

Comment: `'S32'` means one of your arrays is an array of strings, not numbers.  Take a closer look at your arrays and how you create them.  In particular, check `a.dtype` and `b.dtype`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Just taking the input from BrenBarn and Warren Weckesser to provide a code snippet which should run (by converting your strings to float):

```
a = map(lambda x: float(x),a)
b = map(lambda x: float(x),b)
np.dot(a,b.T)
```

or simpler as suggested by @JLT

```
a = map(float,a)
b = map(float,b)
np.dot(a,b.T)
```

But as Warren Weckesser already said, you should check the types of the array, most likely one already contains floats.

Comment: wouldn't map(float, a) be simpler?

Answer (score 17):

Try converting whole numpy array into float
Example:

```
train = train.astype(float)
train_target = train_target.astype(float)
```