# Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'

Tags: python, django, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas, mlp

I am using a sklearn MLPClassifier class and am getting the error: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('

I have a function that converts the string entry to a list
Function:

```
def listinha_da_amanda(entrada):
listinha = []
auxiliar_lista = ''
for i in range(len(entrada)):
    if (entrada[i] != ','):
        auxiliar_lista += entrada[i]
    elif (entrada[i] == ','):
        listinha.append(auxiliar_lista)
        auxiliar_lista = ''

return listinha


def rna(entrada):
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
base = pd.read_csv('app/sonotas.csv')

previsores = base.iloc[:, 1:10].values
classe = base.iloc[:, 10].values

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
previsores = scaler.fit_transform(previsores)

from sklearn.neural_network import MLPClassifier
classificador = MLPClassifier(verbose=True, max_iter=1000, solver='adam', hidden_layer_sizes=(12), activation='relu')
classificador.fit(previsores, classe)

resolv = listinha_da_amanda(entrada)
resolv2 = []
resolv2.append(resolv)

resultado = classificador.predict(resolv2)

return resultado
```

Input Example: 9,8.6,6,7.6,8.1,7.8,8.3,9.4,8.9,

I am using the Django framework.

Comment: Your first function is ok, which line is throwing this error?

Comment: can you upload the data?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173101/numpy-dot-typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypefloat64-to-dtypes32