# TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') for KNN Text Classification in Python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, text-classification, knn

I have the following code:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from csv import reader,writer
import operator as op
import string
from sklearn import neighbors

#Read data from corpus
r = reader(open('one100words.csv','r'))
abstract_list = []
score_list = []
institute_list = []
row_count = 0
for row in list(r)[1:]:
    institute,score,abstract = row[0], row[1], row[2]
    if len(abstract.split()) > 0:
      institute_list.append(institute)
      score = float(score)
      if score >= 3.2:
          score = 3.2
      elif (score >= 3.0 and score < 3.2):
          score = 3.0
      elif (score >= 2.8 and score < 3.0):
          score = 2.8
      elif (score >= 2.5 and score < 2.8):
          score = 2.5
      elif (score >= 2.2 and score < 2.5):
          score = 2.2
      elif (score >= 2.0 and score < 2.2):
          score = 2.0
      elif (score >= 1.5 and score < 2.0):
          score = 1.5
      elif (score >= 1.0 and score < 1.5):
          score = 1.0
      score_list.append(score)
      abstract = abstract.translate(string.punctuation).lower()
      abstract_list.append(abstract)
      row_count = row_count + 1

print("Total processed data: ", row_count)

#Vectorize (TF-IDF, ngrams 1-4, no stop words) using sklearn -->
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1,4),
                     min_df = 0, stop_words = 'english', sublinear_tf=True)
response = vectorizer.fit_transform(abstract_list)
classes = score_list
feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names()

#clf = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=1)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(response, classes)

abstract_input = "Originality: First to combine optimization and first order query processing in relational learning. Significance: Markov Logic was considered to be impractical for most NLP applications. This work changed this, and is the basis of a software (2000+ downloads) used throughout the world. E.g., Henry Kautz, inventor of the MaxWalkSAT (MWS) algorithm, used our algorithm in place of his own MWS. James Allen, inventor of Allen's Temporal Interval Algebra used our tool for temporal reasoning. Rigour: Theoretical analysis proves optimality (or epsilon-optimality). For two real-world models  orders of magnitude reduction in runtime and memory usage at no loss of accuracy."

predicted = clf.predict([[abstract_input]])
```

I am trying to use KNN for text classification. However, I am getting the error in the last line of code as follows:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('U32') according to the rule 'safe'

The complete traceback of the error is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "knn-custom.py", line 58, in <module>
    predicted = clf.predict([[abstract_input]])
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 256, in predict
    return self._decision_function(X)
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/linear_model/base.py", line 241, in _decision_function
    dense_output=True) + self.intercept_
  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/utils/extmath.py", line 140, in safe_sparse_dot
    return np.dot(a, b)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'
```

Anyone knows how to resolve this error or issue?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. Although there is a solution for similar error, however, the solution is not fit for this test case. Existing answer: [Numpy.dot TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173101/numpy-dot-typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypefloat64-to-dtypes32)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy.dot TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('S32') according to the rule 'safe'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173101/numpy-dot-typeerror-cannot-cast-array-data-from-dtypefloat64-to-dtypes32)

Comment: @PV8 I know that error exists but the solution is not applicable for the case that I am using for. So, could you please verify the question?! Thanks in advance.